# Solr reload vs restart

Tags: solrcloud

I am using solr-5.4.0 in my production environment(solr cloud mode) and am trying to automate the reload/restart process of the solr collections based on certain specific conditions.

I noticed that on solr reload the thread count increases a lot there by resulting in increased latencies. So I read about reload process and came to know that while reloading

1) Solr creates a new core internally and then assigns this core same name as the old core. Is this correct?

2) If above is true then does solr actually create a new index internally on reload?

3) If so then restart sounds much better than reload, or is there any better way to upload new configs on solr?

4) Can you point me to any docs that can give me more details about this?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not wrong you wanted to restart/reload the collection in production (Solr cloud mode) and asking for the best approach, If that's true here are few points for the consideration-

If possible, Could you please provide more details like what it cause/requirement to reload/restart the collection in production

I’m assuming the reason could be to refresh the shared resource (Like to see the changes of updated synonyms, or adding or deleting a stop word, etc.) or to update the Solr config set.

Here are a few points for the consideration-

If you want to update the shared resources –

1. Upload the resources through Solr API and reload the collection through (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-Input.1)
   If you want to update the config set –
2. When running in SolrCloud mode, changes made to the schema on one node will propagate to all replicas in the collection. You can pass the updateTimeoutSecs parameter with your request to set the number of seconds to wait until all models confirm they applied the schema updates. ( I got this information from solr-5.4.0, and it’s similar to what we have in Solr 6.6  here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html)

1) Solr creates a new core internally and then assigns this same core name as the old core. Is this correct?

Not sure about it. Can you please share some reference?

2) If above is true then does solr create a new index internally on reload?

Not sure about it. Can you please share some reference?

3) If so then restart sounds much better than reload, or is there any better way to upload new configs on solr?

I don’t agree, because ideally reload is part of the restart, as per my understanding there will be an additional process in reset related to caching and sync.

4) Can you point me to any docs that can give me more details about this?

Here is a link for reference guide-  https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.4.pdf